# ADO.NET MSAccess Update fails because WHERE clause with parameters won't hit

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledbcommand

I seem to have a weird problem and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
My code should update a record but it won't.

```
IDbCommand cmd = ((IConnectionProvider) _Tender).Connection.CreateCommand();

if(_ID == null)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ELEMENTS (ID, HOP, HMODE, HSORT, HFLAGS, KPARENT, TEMPLATE, NUMV, NAMV, TITLE, TXTV, RESERVED, CDATA, VDATA) VALUES (@id, @hop, @hmode, @hsort, @hflags, @kparent, @template, @numv, @namv, @title, @txtv, @reserved, @cdata, @vdata)";
    _ID = _CreateID();
    _Tender.Factory._Cache.Add(_ID, this);
}
else
{
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ELEMENTS SET HOP = @hop, HMODE = @hmode, HSORT = @hsort, HFLAGS = @hflags, KPARENT = @kparent, TEMPLATE = @template, NUMV = @numv, NAMV = @namv, TITLE = @title, TXTV = @txtv, RESERVED = @reserved, CDATA = @cdata, VDATA = @vdata WHERE ID = @id";
}

cmd.AddParameter("@id", _ID);
cmd.AddParameter("@hop", _ActualType);
cmd.AddParameter("@hmode", _Mode);
cmd.AddParameter("@hsort", _Sort);
cmd.AddParameter("@hflags", _Flags);
cmd.AddParameter("@kparent", ((_Parent == null) ? "" : _Parent.ID));
cmd.AddParameter("@template", ((_Template == null) ? "" : _Template.ToString()));
cmd.AddParameter("@numv", _Number);
cmd.AddParameter("@namv", _Name);
cmd.AddParameter("@title", _Title);
cmd.AddParameter("@txtv", _Text);
cmd.AddParameter("@reserved", _Reserved);
cmd.AddParameter("@cdata", _CData);
cmd.AddParameter("@vdata", _VData);

int v = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The INSERT part works just fine. The UPDATE part doesn't update the record for reasons I can't understand. v in the last statement is 0.

If I put the command text like that:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ELEMENTS SET HOP = @hop, HMODE = @hmode, HSORT = @hsort, HFLAGS = @hflags, KPARENT = @kparent, TEMPLATE = @template, NUMV = @numv, NAMV = @namv, TITLE = @title, TXTV = @txtv, RESERVED = @reserved, CDATA = @cdata, VDATA = @vdata WHERE ID = '" + _ID + "'";
```

(not using a bind variable in the WHERE clause) it works (v == 1).

I'm using the interfaces for portability reasons, I wrote AddParameter() extension methods for convenience.
_ID is an alphanumeric value like "g5fRRa3P89gX" or something.

```
_Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";");

public static IDbDataParameter AddParameter(this IDbCommand cmd, string name, DbType type, object value)
{
    IDbDataParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();

    p.DbType = type;
    p.ParameterName = name;
    p.Value = value;

    if(value is string)
    {
        p.Size = ((string) value).Length;
        if(p.Size == 0) { p.Size = 1; }
    }
    else
    {
        p.Size = sizeof(int);
    }

    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    return p;
}

public static IDbDataParameter AddParameter(this IDbCommand cmd, string name, string value)
{
    return AddParameter(cmd, name, DbType.String, value);
}

public static IDbDataParameter AddParameter(this IDbCommand cmd, string name, int value)
{
    return AddParameter(cmd, name, DbType.Int32, value);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about that?
Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it is less awkward as I had thought. It seems the driver simply doesn't support *named* parameters. This is somehow strange because you can define and use them, but apparently they will always be applied in the order they were added to the command disregarding their names.
Thus, the code will work for the UPDATE part when @id parameter is assigned last...